# How to Join 2 table with json key in Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, join

I have 2 table

```
CREATE TABLE json_data_table(d_id int, d1_json json, d2_json json);
CREATE TABLE user_data(uid int, username varchar);
```

and data respectively are

```
INSERT INTO user_data VALUES
(1,'test_user_1'),
(2,'test_user_2'),
(3,'test_user_3');

INSERT INTO json_data_table VALUES 
  (1,'{"stage1":1,"stage2":2 }', '{
    "stage1": {
        "date": "12-01-2023",
        "status": "open",
        "uid": "2"
    },
    "stage2": {
        "date": "22-01-2023",
        "status": "close",
        "uid": "1"
    }
}'),
  (2,'{"stage1":11,"stage2":21 }', '{
    "stage1": {
        "date": "21-2-2023",
        "status": "open",
        "uid": "3"
    },
    "stage2": {
        "date": "2-2-2023",
        "status": "close",
        "uid": "2"
    }
}');
```

Now i want to join `user_data` table with `json_data_table` with `uid` to get `username`

**Expected table output:**

[image]

I got the other columns by simply fetching `json->>key_name` here is `select` query.

```
SELECT d1_json->>'stage1' as stage1, 
       d1_json->>'stage2' as stage2, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'date' as s1_date, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'status' as s1_status, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'uid' as s1_uid,  
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'date' as s2_date, 
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'status' as s2_status, 
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'uid' as s2_uid 
FROM json_data_table AS jd;
```

How to join table to get expected table as shown in image?

Comment: Advice: Store the UID also in a separate column in json_data_table and create a proper foreign key, including an index. This gives you relational integrity, performance and easier SQL because the joins are straight forward

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for the suggestion, will check into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  d1_json ->> 'stage1' as stage1, 
  d1_json ->> 'stage2' as stage2, 
  d2_json -> 'stage1' ->> 'date' as s1_date, 
  d2_json -> 'stage1' ->> 'status' as s1_status, 
  d2_json -> 'stage1' ->> 'uid' as s1_uid, 
    s1_user.username as s1_username, 
  d2_json -> 'stage2' ->> 'date' as s2_date, 
  d2_json -> 'stage2' ->> 'status' as s2_status, 
  d2_json -> 'stage2' ->> 'uid' as s2_uid, 
  s2_user.username as s2_username 
FROM 
  json_data_table AS jd 
  JOIN user_data s2_user ON s2_user.uid :: TEXT = d2_json -> 'stage2' ->> 'uid' :: TEXT 
  JOIN user_data s1_user ON s1_user.uid :: TEXT = d2_json -> 'stage1' ->> 'uid' :: TEXT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just join it and use the expression to extract the `uid` in the join condition.
And since you need to different sets of `user_data` you need to join the table twice.
And finally since `uid` is a number and JSON consists of text you have to convert between the two.
I opted to do the conversion on the JSON side, since this enables usage of an index for `user_data` which seems reasonable to exist in the real use case.

```sql
SELECT d1_json->>'stage1' as stage1, 
       d1_json->>'stage2' as stage2, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'date' as s1_date, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'status' as s1_status, 
       d2_json->'stage1'->>'uid' as s1_uid,  
       s1ud.username as s1_username,
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'date' as s2_date, 
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'status' as s2_status, 
       d2_json->'stage2'->>'uid' as s2_uid,  
       s2ud.username as s2_username 
FROM json_data_table AS jd
join user_data s1ud
on s1ud.uid = to_number( d2_json->'stage1'->>'uid', '999')
join user_data s2ud
on s2ud.uid = to_number( d2_json->'stage2'->>'uid', '999');
```

[DB-Fiddle to play with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hEWPp1VJNywdvD1rZCRBfB/0).